# How to read if the UUID format from a json file?

Tags: json, regex, uuid

I have a json file say file.json 
It has a json body like this

```
{
   "input": {
   "url": "/abc/def/efg/{UUID}.txt",
   "type": "text"
},
   "output": {
   "result": 10,
   "content": ""
   }
}
```

`{UUID}` is any valid UUID.

How do I allow any UUID as regex / generic form in place {UUID} ??

Comment: What are you actually asking? What language/tool are you using? What attempts have you made to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you want to match the GUID in your text? Please explain more.

Comment: Yes, I want to match the GUID in my text @PoulBak

Comment: what type of uuid is that? there are various versions of uuid

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to find and match the 'GUID' part or your text:

```
/\"url\":\s?\"[^{]+\{([^}]+)/
```

The regex matches `'"url": "'` at start, then matches up to '`{`' before it creates a Group where it stores the `'UUID'`

You get an array as result, where you should grap `Group 1`.

How to use:

if your text is in a variable called `'text'`, then you can do:

```
var UUID = text.match(/\"url\":\s?\"[^{]+\{([^}]+)/)[1];
```